# AWS Load balancer to only support HTTPS and auto redirection to HTTPS for user trying to access HTTP

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS to run my application based on MEAN stack. I am using load balancer with three instances of Node application servers and three instances of mongo database server on cluster. Following is my requirement.
1. Use load balancer to support only HTTPS
2. Node should run the HTTP server only
3. Load balancer will redirect HTTPS and HTTP both request to Apache which will redirect to Node

I tried AWS and created Load balancer. HTTPS only works when I keep both 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) port redirection to 80 (HTTP) port of Apache node. Therefore as of now I kept both port redirection on load balancer.

Also, I have defined both 80 and 443 inbound traffic as security group.

How can I make sure that even if user type HTTP or HTTPS URL in the browser, my load balancer should always server HTTPS and user should only access HTTPS? Following is architecture diagram for reference.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

At the load balancer, direct the port 80 listener to port 8080 on the instance.

In Apache, rewrite port 8080 to port 443.

E.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The RewriteCond may be redundent...